# Jiggly Text problems ( Jello like text is not behaving the way I want w physics )

Tags: modeling

I'm totally new here. I don't even know how to add a blend file yet, I just joined this site now.

Goal:
Chinese characters in 3D, and similar to noob jello cube tutorials on youtube, I want to turn them into soft bodies and collision, and raise them up a bit on z axis, and animate the jello chinese characters falling down a short way and jiggling around a bit.

Problem:
The Chinese characters need to remain in their shape a bit as if they are connected.
[image]
(B) And (C) are in the same character. If I hit tab > edit mode, they are the same object, same mesh. But when I add physics (C) will hit the ground first and jiggle. But then (B) falls too far and runs into (C). But the gap between (B) and (C) was supposed to remain about the same, aside from some jiggling.

Also, the characters all want to fall down near the end of the animation. I can't get them to stand upright properly after the gravity and collision animation is over. For example (A) won't find an upright position after all is said and done. It always falls over or leans on another character. All the characters don't find their original shape enough or stand up in the end. Instead they jiggle around like jello and fall all over the place.

Sorry for the wall of text and sheer noobishness.

Comment: Welcome to SE. You can easily provide your blend file by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions. And don't worry - your explanation is really great and understandable and by far better than the most "first time problem"-descriptions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would connect B + C into one mesh and just visually separate them via color (transparent).
How good or stabile they stand on the floor after the animation depends on your soft body settings + mesh.

If you provide blend file, we can work on that ;)

Comment: they are already the same mesh. But i think I know what you mean, connect them with invisible mesh! That's brilliant, thanks for your quick response :)
I'll be at this for a while and post again later about the falling over issue. And I'll learn how to upload a blend file.

Comment: Chris, how is your English so good? You help me as if you are a native speaker. Greetings from USA to Germany and thanks again for the help.

Comment: @cello: thank you‼️ but my English is not as good as it could be . I learnt it at school and a bit more at my former work. Greetings back to USA!

Comment: You don't have to use material/transparency since you will deal with hole in depth. Sim is based on edges not faces. So it should be enough to just connect separate parts by edges that are not rendered.